# Two NSFetchedResultsControllers with Magical Record

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uitableview, magicalrecord, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two UITableviewControllers. In each controller I use a NSFetchedResultsController to populate the table.
I am trying to use Magical Record for the CoreData part and this is working great with one FetchedResultsController, but as soon as I try to load the second FetchedResultsController, my app crashes. 
I think it has something to do with not using the correct NSManagedObjectContext, but I think I am following the examples so I dont' really now how to do it correctly.

Here is the code I use:

TableViewController 1

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [News MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"main_id"
                                                    ascending:YES
                                                withPredicate:nil
                                                      groupBy:nil
                                                     delegate:self
                                                    inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext   MR_context]];
```

TableViewController 2

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [Event MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"id"
                                                    ascending:YES
                                                withPredicate:nil
                                                      groupBy:nil
                                                     delegate:self
                                                     inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_context]];
```

For saving I use:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
[context MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:NULL];
```

And:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
[context MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:NULL];
```

I really hope someone can explain what I am doing wrong as I am really stuck at this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I have the saving working now, so no error there anymore (apparently I was using a wrong key to sort by), but still the tableviewcontroller isn't populated. So I still have the feeling that the NSManagedObjectContexts aren't paired correctly.
Some parts of MagicalRecord are very confusing to me although it is a great tool.

Comment: Are you handling the FRC delegate methods ?

Comment: Yes, I use the controllerDidChangeContent, controllerDidChangeSection, didChangeObject and willChangeContent delegate methods.

By the way, the tableview does get populated, but only after I restart the application. So when I start with an empty database, the tableview doesn't get populated after saving the entities. After restarting the application, the entities are shown in the tableview.

Comment: So the issue is likely with the core data stack and how you have created and associated the MOCs (parent - child / save notifications).

Comment: This is what I have done to set it up:

**'[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"DataModel.sqlite"];'**

And for the contexts I use the ones as posted above. Is there anything else I have to initialize. By the way, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Do you have an example of the crash you see

Comment: At the moment I have no crash. MagicalRecord seems to be saving ok, but only the NSFetchedResultsController doesn't populate the tableview on the first run of the app.